# google maps: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps

These days i meet a problem about google maps api,it confuses me a long time,could anyboby help me?  this is my first question in english,maybe i made some inappropriate remarks, sorry...Finally thanks very much!

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.apple.lbs" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyD6_QTxOVUyGs2Fl7mb7Sf5Azjb0InxyjM"/>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Mainactivity.java:

```
package com.example.apple.lbs;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

```css
logcat:

    03-29 18:17:47.355    2533-2545/com.example.apple.lbs I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1472(74KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 13% free, 537KB/623KB, paused 14.599ms total 275.442ms
    03-29 18:17:47.482    2533-2545/com.example.apple.lbs W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.954ms
    03-29 18:17:47.499    2533-2545/com.example.apple.lbs I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 86(18KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 48% free, 539KB/1051KB, paused 7.714ms total 78.785ms
    03-29 18:17:47.912    2533-2533/com.example.apple.lbs I/zzx﹕ Making Creator dynamically
    03-29 18:17:47.929    2533-2533/com.example.apple.lbs W/ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
    03-29 18:17:47.931    2533-2533/com.example.apple.lbs W/ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
    03-29 18:17:48.391    2533-2545/com.example.apple.lbs I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 487(48KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 1293KB/1293KB, paused 1.827ms total 180.785ms
    03-29 18:17:48.441    2533-2545/com.example.apple.lbs W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 28.533ms
    03-29 18:17:48.445    2533-2545/com.example.apple.lbs I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 87(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 28% free, 1297KB/1809KB, paused 30.116ms total 51.022ms
    03-29 18:17:48.713    2533-2533/com.example.apple.lbs I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services client version: 7095000
    03-29 18:17:48.817    2533-2533/com.example.apple.lbs I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services package version: 7097470
    03-29 18:17:49.311    2533-2545/com.example.apple.lbs W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.286ms
    03-29 18:17:49.318    2533-2545/com.example.apple.lbs I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 89(7KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 4% free, 1722KB/1809KB, paused 9.690ms total 37.156ms
    03-29 18:17:50.157    2533-2533/com.example.apple.lbs D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    03-29 18:17:50.207    2533-2533/com.example.apple.lbs E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.apple.lbs, PID: 2533
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.apple.lbs/com.example.apple.lbs.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
                at com.example.apple.lbs.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
         Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
                at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ck.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.i.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.el.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ab.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.aa.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.x.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
                at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
                at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1045)
                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1147)
                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2116)
                at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5286)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
                ... 19 more
```

Comment: read a bit further in your stacktrace: there is the cause, somehow it is not recognizing you permissions

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: but i compiled these codes totally accroding to developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/…, i really don't know where is the error occurred .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By watching your Android manifest, i think error occurs because you have **uses-permission** tag inside you **application** tag, please move all your **uses-permission** code before **application** tag.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.apple.lbs" >

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
            <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

 <uses-feature
                android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
                android:required="true"/>

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyD6_QTxOVUyGs2Fl7mb7Sf5Azjb0InxyjM"/>


            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Think you very much ! but now it just show a white view not a map,how can i solve it?

Comment: Please mark my answer if it solved your issue and if it is a white view then can you see Google written on bottom left hand side of the screen. Please share a screen shot.